# Error: Number is out of range

Tags: nodeos, transactions, api

I am trying to create and account from another account, both on JungleNet. I am using junglenet rpc. Here is my code:

```
const {Api, JsonRpc} = require('eosjs');
const {JsSignatureProvider} = require('eosjs/dist/eosjs-jssig');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const {TextDecoder, TextEncoder} = require('util');
const { PrivateKey } = require('eosjs-ecc');

const privateKey1 = 'REDACTED';

const privateKeys = [privateKey1];
const publicKey = PrivateKey.fromString(privateKey1).toPublic().toString();

const signatureProvider = new JsSignatureProvider(['REDACTED']);
const rpc = new JsonRpc('http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:80', {fetch});
const api = new Api({rpc, signatureProvider, textDecoder: new TextDecoder(), textEncoder: new TextEncoder()});

(async () => {
    const res = await api.transact({
        expiration: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 30 * 60000),
        ref_block_num: '65990145',
        ref_block_prefix: '2469844007',
        actions: [{
            account: 'eosio',
            name: 'newaccount',
            authorization: [{
                actor: 'winterwind12',
                permission: 'active',
            }],
            data: {
                creator: 'winterwind12',
                name: 'winterwind14',
                owner:{
                    threshold: 1,
                    keys: [{
                        key: 'EOS5ZWJYNoFUYN62iQRc77LEdY2GfmRxLUgsbtWwMstJWbJwGMPHs',
                        weight: 1
                    }],
                    accounts: [],
                    waits: []
                },
                active: {
                    threshold: 1,
                    keys: [{
                        key: 'EOS5ZWJYNoFUYN62iQRc77LEdY2GfmRxLUgsbtWwMstJWbJwGMPHs',
                        weight: 1
                    }],
                    accounts: [],
                    waits: []
                },
            },
        },
        {
            account: 'eosio',
            name: 'buyrambytes',
            authorization: [{
                actor: 'winterwind12',
                permission: 'active',
            }],
            data: {
                payer: 'winterwind12',
                receiver: 'winterwind14',
                bytes: 8192
            },
        },
        {
            account: 'eosio',
            name: 'delegatebw',
            authorization: [{
                actor: 'winterwind12',
                permission: 'active',
            }],
            data: {
                from: 'winterwind12',
                receiver: 'winterwind14',
                stake_net_quantity: '0.5000 SYS',
                stake_cpu_quantity: '0.5000 SYS',
                transfer: false,
            }
        }]
    })
    // {broadcast: false, sign: true})
    // {blocksBehind: 3, expireSeconds: 30})

    console.log(res);
})();
```

After executing this, I get an error like this:

```
(node:20637) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Number is out of range
    at checkRange (/home/hasnain/Projects/EOS/Test/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-serialize.js:690:15)
    at Object.serialize (/home/hasnain/Projects/EOS/Test/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-serialize.js:719:68)
    at Object.serializeStruct [as serialize] (/home/hasnain/Projects/EOS/Test/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-serialize.js:564:28)
    at Object.serializeStruct [as serialize] (/home/hasnain/Projects/EOS/Test/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-serialize.js:555:19)
    at Api.serialize (/home/hasnain/Projects/EOS/Test/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-api.js:245:41)
    at Api.serializeTransaction (/home/hasnain/Projects/EOS/Test/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-api.js:254:14)
    at Api.<anonymous> (/home/hasnain/Projects/EOS/Test/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-api.js:380:54)
    at step (/home/hasnain/Projects/EOS/Test/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-api.js:47:23)
    at Object.next (/home/hasnain/Projects/EOS/Test/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-api.js:28:53)
    at fulfilled (/home/hasnain/Projects/EOS/Test/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-api.js:19:58)
(node:20637) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:20637) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Where am I going wrong with my code?

Answer (score -1):

Your stake_net_quantity number is error. You have to use 4 precision.

You can find the details : [2.2. Initialize system account](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence)

eosio.system config the decimal point.

Comment: I don't understand, stake_net_quantity already has 4 digits after decimal. Moreover, I debugged my code and found that the error is at the expiration. It has wrong format. I wrote the format mentioned in the docs, i.e. `expiration: '2019-09-19T16:39:15'` and it still gives me the same error